# Deleting first two lines by including one liner in perl

Tags: perl

I got the below file as an output of a script:-

```
----Local Rates----

Market Merchant SE number mismatch Dupe Check S.Number Local Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec FY
Abc Asfinag  1 9406589846 EUR 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 1,125 13,500
Abc BÖG  1 #N/A! EUR 844 844 844 844 844 844 844 844 844 844 844 844 10,125
Abc Gault Millau  1 9496732942 EUR 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 3,375 40,500
Abc OEGV  1 9404123606 EUR 187 187 187 187 187 187 187 187 187 187 187 187 2,244
Abc Relax Guide  1 9404130395 EUR 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 8,100
Abc Sport 2000  1 9495264095 EUR 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 608
Abc Strategic Investment Pool  1 #N/A! EUR 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 1,980 23,760
Abc Strolz  1 #N/A! EUR 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 3,375
Abc Urlaubsspezialisten  1 Urlaubsspezialisten EUR 619 619 619 619 619 619 619 619 619 619 619 619 7,425
Abc Vamed  1 9404119554 EUR 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 3,375
Abc Vienna Fashion Night  1 Vienna Fashion Night EUR 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 1,688 20,250
Abc Vineus / C&C Pfeifer  1 Vineus / C&C Pfeifer EUR 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 1,012 12,150
Abc IKEA  1 #N/A! EUR 394 394 394 394 394 394 394 394 394 394 394 394 4,725
Abc REWE  1 9502932411 EUR 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 675 8,100
```

I got the above output by using below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'File' or die "Can't open file: $!\n";

while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = split(/\t/);
    print "@fields[0,1,3,4,5,6,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33]\n";
}
```

Now I am trying to remove first two lines, so I want to use the below one line into the script, but I'm unable to incorporate it.

```
perl -i.bak -ne '$.>=4 && print' file
```

What should I do?

Comment: You can use ranges to make the fields more readable: `(0, 1, 3..6, 21..33)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing this, the logic is just reversed, I just added the line

```
$. <= 2 and next;
```

to your own code :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'File' or die "Can't open file: $!\n";

while (<$fh>) {
    $. <= 2 and next;
    my @fields = split(/\t/);
    print "@fields[0,1,3,4,5,6,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33]\n";
}
```

Comment: I find the `next if` formulation more intuitive than this use of `and`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599765/reading-specific-column-from-an-excel-in-perl

Answer (score 3):

You don't need external one liner to skip first two lines,

```
while (<$fh>) {
  next if $. <= 2;

  # ..
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wrote before =)

Comment: @sputnick yes, six seconds to be exact. `:)`

Comment: No, 50 secondes IIRC ;)

Comment: Thank You guys!!
But my real problem is to club two scripts to one, and I am very new to Perl I had post a query in diffrent post.. Hope you help me in that too..
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599765/reading-specific-column-from-an-excel-in-perl)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same by having an if condition with the print i.e., if $. > 2 .

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
open my $fh, '<', 'File' or die "Can't open file: $!\n";
while (<$fh>) {
    my @fields = split(/\t/);
    print "@fields[0,1,3,4,5,6,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33]\n" if $. > 2;
}
```